# Struct and variables in C

Tags: c, struct

My struct looks like this:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *A;
    struct Node *B;
    struct Node *C;
    struct Node *D;
    struct Node *E;
    struct Node *F;
    struct Node *G;
    struct Node *H;
    struct Node *I;
};

typedef struct Node *List;
```

And i'm trying to access one of "subnodes" via list->znak, where 'znak' is variable. However i'm getting error:

error: ‘struct Node’ has no member named ‘znak’

I don't know how to "tell" C that char is a variable.

I've written char, because "znak" mean char in my language.

Comment: `char` is a reserved word, C will be angry if you use it.

Comment: znak isn't reserved though and he can use that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, struct field names do not exist during runtime so you cannot convert a runtime character or string into a struct offset like you can in some scripting languages. In your case, I would use an array of `Node *` instead of having 10 separate fields.

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *children[9];
}
```

And to access the array you convert the characters to an array index by comparing them to the first character in your sequence.

```
struct Node* list = /*...*/;
int znak = 'D';
list->children[znak - 'A'] = /*...*/
```

Of course, once you start using an array instead of named fields, perhaps its going to be simpler to have `znak` be an integer index instead of a character in between A and I.

Comment: This is the only reply so far that actually offers a solution to the problem and is worthy of a dedicated answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But when i'll do it via array would I be able to do something like this: int test = list->children[2]->children[5]->value? Sorry if it's a nooby question, i'm new to C.

Comment: @user2511670: Yes, that should work just fine. `list->children[2]` is also a `Node *` so you can use `->` on it.

Comment: Yes you would be able to do that as long as you don't hit a "NULL" or other invalid pointer along the way.

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee that the characters “A” through “I” are consecutive. They are in common C implementations, including ASCII and EBCDIC, but code using this would fail if extended behind “I” and compiled for an EBCDIC implementation. At a minimum, the requirement that the characters be consecutive should be specified in the documentation for the source code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: You are right, but to be practical, what are the odds that OP is going to compile this for an old mainframe using EBCDIC?

Comment: @missingno: What happens with code is that somebody writes it, they share it, somebody modifies it, and the code lives for years. Eventually, somebody tries to use it on a new platform, and it has bugs because it was written without good practices. The time to form good practices is when people are learning: It is harder to teach somebody to unlearn a bad habit than it is to teach a good habit at the start. And all I have stated is that **the non-standard requirement should be documented**. Simply documenting a requirement transforms buggy code into code that conforms to its specification.

Comment: @missingno: Also, there are modern systems using EBCDIC.

Answer (score 0):

Char is a reserved word in the C language - you cannot define a variable named 'char'
[link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pdthelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.debugtool.doc_8.1/eqa8ug02426.htm)

Comment: Char isn't reserved only char is

Answer (score 0):

There's no member named `znak` in the `struct`, hence the compiler won't allow you to use it as a member.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, char is a reserved word in C. But additionally, the compiled code may not encode the letter of the node, since such names in a program are merely for human understanding. What you want to do is to use a hashtable or enums to assign the nodes, i.e., have an array of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct Node has 10 members, called value, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H and I.

There is no member called znak.

What you are wanting is for "znak" to mean `&Node::A` and then later to mean `&Node::B` which you can actually do in C++ but not in C, after which you access it through operator `->*` or `.*`

Of course just because it can be done doesn't mean it is the right thing to do and even if your code were C++ here I would suggest simply having an array (or in C++ a vector) of your node pointers after which you can simply pass in an index to the one you want to access presumably in each of your items.